# Automator "Get specified finder items" applescript equivalent

Tags: applescript, automator

I have routines that I'd like to make universal: instead of the selected folders, I'd like to stick to the user current user ("~/") when describing folder paths..

So my question is, if I select a folder with "Get Specified Finder Items" in automator, that outputs a -non applescript- list like this: ("path/to/my/folder"), how can I replicate it with applescript. Note the round brackets instead of the braces!

First I simply wanted to use this:

```
on run
  return {"~/path/to/my/folder/under/current/user"}
end run
```

And then I'd add the "Get Folder Contents" block..

Can anyone tell me why this wouldn't work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: of course, there would be more folders in the list.. thats why I need a list in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I might as well post what I was typing up for you anyway :-)

```
set folderTest1 to "test1"
set folderTest2 to "test2"


set homePath to POSIX path of (path to home folder as text) as text
set attachmentsFolder to (homePath & folderTest1 & "/" & folderTest2) as text

--OR


set homePath to POSIX path of (path to home folder as text) as text
set attachmentsFolder to (homePath & "test1/test2") as text
```

*POSIX PATH* changes the HFS+ path to a unix type path

*path to home* folder  get to the users  home folder

*path to documents* get the path to the users documents folder

*POSIX file* changes the unix type path to a  HFS+ path

```
set homePath to POSIX path of (path to home folder as text) as text


set theHFSPath to (POSIX file homePath)
tell application "Finder"
    --The finder looks for the folders in the alais path of theHFSPath
    set theFolders to folders of (theHFSPath as alias) as alias list

    --> returns is a list of folders in the form of alais paths

end tell
```

Comment: I eventually solved it with the following syntax:

`return {alias ((path to home folder as text) & "Library:Caches:Adobe Camera Raw" as text)}`

Ans since this was in a "Run AppleScript" block in my automator app, I just attached the "Get Folder Contents" and the "Move Finder Items toTrash" blocks.. This way it's universal, and I can send it to colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following code:

```
on run
return { POSIX path of ((path to home folder as text)) & "/path to my folder" as text, .. }
end run
```

Comment: It could be shortened to `{(system attribute "HOME") & "/path to my folder"}`. Scripts have an implicit run handler and they return the last value. `system attribute "HOME"` is the same as $HOME.

Comment: I eventually solved it with the following syntax: `return {alias ((path to home folder as text) & "Library:Caches:Adobe Camera Raw" as text)}` Ans since this was in a "Run AppleScript" block in my automator app, I just attached the "Get Folder Contents" and the "Move Finder Items toTrash" blocks.. This way it's universal, and I can send it to colleagues.